# Generating random id name

Tags: javascript, testing, random, jquery-selectors, dynamically-generated

I tried to generate id name and put it in field .But, I'm stuck on putting a generated name to test.

html element with id:

```
<CIconButton id = {carrier.name + '_remove'} icon="delete" onClick={handleDelete(carrier.id)} />
```

At this moment, deleting via static id ;

```
  AdminCarriersPage.setCarrierName("CarrierTestCafe");
this.removeCarrierButton = Selector("[id=CarrierTestCafe_remove]");
    await t.click(this.removeCarrierButton);
```

But it should be generated. What i tried to do:
firstly, generated name with faker:

```
const randomCarrierName = faker.fake('{{name.firstName}}');
```

I'm stucked with putting a generated name

```
const deleteCarrier = Selector(`${randomCarrierName} + '_remove'`);
 
  await t.click(deleteCarrier);
```